# How to correctly apply the google services plugin?

Tags: android, plugins, google-play-services

I am working on a project, and I need to apply the google services plugin to my code. I have done so in the build.gradle project and module, but I keep receiving the following warning every time I run my app.

Please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the build file.

Any help would be great!

Also, I am a beginner to coding, and it may be important to note that my app doesn't work. I get a runtime error in the emulator when I try to run it:
________ keeps stopping
app info
close app

Here is my build.gradle Module:app

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 26
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "edmt.dev.androidgeofire"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 26
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {

        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

        androidTestImplementation 
        ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2', {

            exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

        })

        implementation 'com.h6ah4i.android.widget.verticalseekbar:verticalseekbar:0.7.2'

        implementation 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.3.1'

        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.1.0'

        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'

        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.1.0'

        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'

        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'

        }

        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I'm not sure what else I would need to include to help anyone understand, so if anyone needs anything else I would be happy to add it.

Comment: Can you please link the error log ?

Comment: Have you added the classpath to google play service in your build.gradle(project) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your build.gradle(project) like this

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
}
}
```

Don't forget to change

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'
```

to your actual classpath of gradle

Comment: Thanks for your help! I don't have the right computer to access my code right now, but I'll definitely try when I get home.

Comment: Hello again. I finally got the chance to test out my app, and I still get the same error. I'm beginning to think that it might not make a huge difference as it is just a warning.  Now I'm getting a runtime error which simply says "your app keeps stopping". This is an error which pops up in my emulator when I run the app.